# Reference to another page using a variable?

Tags: excel, reference, excel-formula, concatenation

I have the name of the sheets in a column. The value of the next column entirely depends on the column (which is the name of sheets in that workbook) next to it.

For eg.

The value of a cell is `='sheet1'A1`. The value `sheet1` is present in the another cell `B1`. So, I want to use it as `='B1'A1`, where `A3=sheet1`.

Comment: What does `'sheet1'A1` mean? The syntax isn't a valid string, and it's not a valid sheet reference. Or do you mean the value of the cell is the string, `"'sheet1'A1"`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261):

```
=INDIRECT("'"&B1&"'!A1")
```